# Ошибка при установке модуля EmoPy

Tags: python, pip

Устанавливаю модуль EmoPy, как в документации: pip install EmoPy
Выдает ошибку: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement EmoPy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for EmoPy
Было у кого?

Comment: Да, было у кого. https://github.com/thoughtworksarts/EmoPy раздел issues.

Comment: Вижу, что было. Только вопрос там не решен. Буду искать дальше